# How to add a Where clause in Azure Data Factory Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following Azure Data Factory copy activity,

[image]

The query looks like the following:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName)
```

I would like to add a where clause to the query similar to the following:

'SELECT * FROM ',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName)
where parameters.ColumnName(mycolumn) = 'zyx'

I know the above is probably incorrect but is it possible to add a WHERE clause in the query to work with  `@concat('SELECT * FROM ',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName)`

Comment: Hey, Can you please provide a static version of your query here? Yes, The query can have any filter logics within copy activity source

Comment: Hi @Nandan, the query is simple as ```select * from TableA where ColumnName = 'ABCDEFG'  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample expression to form a valid SQL statement in ADF source using dynamic expression when there is a parameter for table name using a where clause.

```
@concat('select * from ', pipeline().parameters.param_TableName, ' where Location = ',' ''Redmond'' ')
```

Or

```
@concat('select * from ', pipeline().parameters.param_TableName, ' where Location ',' = ''Redmond'' ')
```

The above expression will form the below SQL statement at runtime:

```
"sqlReaderQuery": "select * from Employee where Location = 'Redmond'",
```

In your case the query will look like below:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM ',pipeline().parameters.Domain,'.',pipeline().parameters.TableName, 'where ', pipeline().parameters.ColumnName, ' = ''zyx'' ')
```

In simple terms in the where clause of your dynamic expression you will have to add two single quotes to form one single quote during the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

- Using `concat` to build SQL queries would give desired result but you can also try using string interpolation `@{...}` to build queries instead. The following is an example of the same.
- I am using the dynamic content in set variable activity as a demonstration. To build a query that you are expecting, you can give the following dynamic expression directly in the pipeline expression builder.

```
SELECT * FROM @{pipeline().parameters.domain}.@{pipeline().parameters.tablename} where @{pipeline().parameters.col} = 'zyx'
```

[image]

- The above dynamic content would generate the query as shown below:

[image]

- So, wherever you want to use dynamic content in the query, you can simply enclose it within `@{...}`

Comment: Thanks members for reaching out. I'm going try your suggestions in the next few minutes. I will let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Patterson, provide additional details about the issue you are facing if the approach did not work